# Show Success in a JQ UI-widget after form submit, and a redirect from a UI.Dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, coldfusion, dialog

Thanks for even taking a look.

I'm deleting a record from a database. The user confirms the deletion in a JQ UI.Dialog with an Ajax form submit and is then basically redirected to the same page to reload the updated data.

This all works fine and dandy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {


    $( "#delete-invoice" ).click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            $( "#confirmDelModal" ).dialog( "open" );
     });



    $( "#confirmDelModal" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 220,
        width: 680,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete Invoice": function() {
              var options = {   
                    success: function(){
                        $("#confirmDelModal").dialog("close");
                        window.location.href="same-page.cfm";

                    }
                }; 
                $('#confirmDelete').ajaxSubmit(options);

                return false; 
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    });





});
```

After the form submits, I want to show a "Delete Success" message at the top of the page.
[The Highlight/Error boxes on this theme roller page half way down on the right](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Basically, I want to show a hidden Success DIV after redirect/page reload.

I've been learning Ajax over the past few weeks, and making good progress, but still trying to wrap my head around the bigger concepts, so I'm sure there may be a better way of doing this that I'm also totally open to hear, just keep in mind, the designer wants that specific style Message to come up, on success.

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 0 .7em;">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
    <strong>Hey!</strong> Deletion Successful</p>
</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance

PS. Working in Coldfusion

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're doing, but why not just show the success message on submit success instead of reloading the page? This can be done with JavaScript easily enough.

Comment: Some more info that may be helpful:

Comment: The first step is selecting a delete icon, which runs an ajax function that brings up all of the details of that rows data, and text explaining that deleted records can't be retrieved after delete. The dialog I posted above is displayed on another delete button, at the bottom of this second step, and deleting is confirmed in this dialog. The form is submitted on the dialog button, and the database is queried. So instead of redrawing the DIV to the original table with Ajax, I redirect to the same page as a make shift reload. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, you have to send a return value from your modal dialog to the parent page.  Here is an example I wrote a few years ago.  Note that is uses basic javascript, without ajax, but it does show the general idea.

This is on the parent page:

```
<cfoutput>
<script language="JavaScript">
function ServiceOther() {
if (document.Serviceform.service_id.value == "OTHER" ) {

NewContact=window.showModalDialog("#K.QryHome#ComplexCare/Contacts/OutsideNewService.cfm?    callPage=Addf","NewService","Dialogwidth:600px; Dialogheight:420px; center:yes ");

if (NewContact == true) // return value from dialogue
window.location="#K.QryHome#ComplexCare/Contacts/OutsideServices.cfm?callPage=AddWithNew";

} // end if
}// end of function

</script>
</cfoutput>
```

In your case, you want to replace the window.location command with something that displays your message.

In my case, the modal dialog page had a form in it that look like this:

```
<cfform name="SKNewContactform" Action="ProcessNewOutsideService.cfm" method="post" 
onsubmit="window.returnValue = true; window.close();">
```

The ProcessNewOutsideService.cfm contains this:

```
<script language=javascript>
function CloseWindow() {
window.open('','_self','');
window.opener = top;
window.close();
}
```

then a bunch of coldfusion code, and finally, this

```
<body onload="window.returnValue = true;  CloseWindow();">
```

Once again, the general idea is for your modal dialog window to send a value to the parent window when it closes.  The parent window can then do something with that value.;

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

To answer your question, you would need to indicate to the server that you want to show the success message when you reload the page. This can be done through the URL using something like a query string.

I wouldn't recommend this though since you would be doing more work than necessary and all you want to do is show a message. You are already deleting the record through AJAX so you can do this from just the client side without requesting the whole page again.

**(Better) Solution**

When you open the first dialog to show details, keep track of the record in the DOM (the page's record, not the database record). An easy way to do this is to just store it in a variable on the icon's click event:

```
$deleteTarget;
$('.delete_icon').click(function() {
    $deleteTarget = $(this).closest('.myRowClass');
});
```

Now if your user deletes the row and you asynchronously delete on the server, you can do the same on the client side:

```
$deleteTarget.remove();
```

...and then show your success message:

```
$('#successMessage').show();
```

Now you can remove the line that reloads the page and just have the dialog close (after doing the above).

I would say this is a better/faster alternative than reloading the page, since the client machine does not need to make another full request to the server (less work for the server), and does not need to reload the page either (less work for the client).

**Late edit:** Just want to add that before you delete the record on the client side, you should make sure it is actually deleted on the server. When you make your request to delete the record, you should wait for a response from the server. If the record is deleted successfully on the server, it should return a response to the client. Once you get a response to show that the delete was successful, you can then delete the record on the client.

Comment: Thank you for the great reply. Very easy to understand. I messed around  and got it to come up by adding a cfif statement to the div displaying the success message, and attached a ?success=1 to the URL in the redirect on submit. I'm sure that will be rife with problems that are over my head, so i'm going to try and implement what you've provided since it just seems more efficient. Thank you, I'll keep you posted on my outcome.

Comment: I hadn't realized that you wanted to reload the entire page.  Since you do, the method you chose is as good as any.  If you are going to use a coldfusion solution, you might want to put the coldfusion tag back on your question so that coldfusion people can see the question.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
window.location.href="same-page.cfm";
```

To:

```
window.location.href="same-page.cfm?deleted=1";
```

And in the CF have:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(url,"deleted")>.. {Div here}..</cfif>
```

And for a bit of flair add in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ $("div.mydiv").fadeOut("slow"); }, 2000);
 });
```